# Android OnPrimaryClipChangedListener in service not working outside app

Tags: java, android, service, background

I try to develop an app in java,
I try to get all clipboard statement whatever inside the app or when the app closed (home button pressed )
I tried a lot of things after searching on the internet but I don't get anything excepted this problem happen with SDK >= 26
------------ steps I do ----------

1. create service
2. define service in the manifest file
3. create a notification channel
4. start service by (startForeground)

**NOTE: THIS WORKING VERY WELL IF I COPY INSIDE APP**

----------------------------------------- **ClipboardMonitorService.java**

```
package com.example.testclipboard;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Monitors the {@link ClipboardManager} for changes and logs the text to a file.
 */
public class ClipboardMonitorService extends Service {


   

 
    private ExecutorService mThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private ClipboardManager mClipboardManager;


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //startForeground();
        // TODO: Show an ongoing notification when this service is running.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else
            startForeground(1, new Notification());

        //mHistoryFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FILENAME);
        mClipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        mClipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(
                mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);


        Log.i("Service Created ","Yes Created !");
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground(){
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.testclipboard";
        String channelName = "My Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_1)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mClipboardManager != null) {
            mClipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(
                    mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }




    private ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener =
            new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {

                    String _string =mClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();

                    logger(_string);
                    ClipData clip = mClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
                    mThreadPool.execute(new WriteHistoryRunnable(
                            clip.getItemAt(0).getText()));
                }
            };


    private void logger(String txt){
        Log.i("Logger : " , txt);
    }


    private class WriteHistoryRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final CharSequence mTextToWrite;

        public WriteHistoryRunnable(CharSequence text) {
            mTextToWrite = text;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mTextToWrite)) {
                // Don't write empty text to the file
                return;
            }


                    Log.i("Copyed : ",mTextToWrite.toString() );
                    String clipboared = mTextToWrite.toString();
                  


                    
                    //writer.newLine();
                    //writer.close();

        }
    }


}
```

--------------------------------------- **MainActivity.java**

````
package com.example.testclipboard;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private Intent forService;
    ClipboardManager myClipBoard ;

    Button btnClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        

        forService = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TestSmallService.class);
        btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btntest);




        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Btn Clicked ","Heyys");

                // ToDO : The Old One

                
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ClipboardMonitorService.class);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    getBaseContext().startForegroundService(intent);

                } else {
                    getBaseContext().startService(intent);
                }
                



            }
        });



    }

    


 
}```
````

Comment: Hi there, what is the error you are getting? Could you include a stacktrace? Thanks!

Comment: @LucasMarcondesPavelski , no any error just service not working in background ! you can try this code and understand what i mean